# Kendo Schedular is not working after updating the kendo 2014 Q3 & knockout-kendo 0.9

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-kendo

I am using kendo scheduler in my Ko based MVVM app,

scheduler is works well in my previous version of Kendo(Q2 2014) and knockout-kendo (0.8).

recently i just updated both kendo(2014 Q3) and konckout-kendo (0.9) it is not working it throws a error like below.

```
Message: Unable to parse bindings.

Bindings value: kendoScheduler: {
....}

Message: Unexpected token (;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by done the following changes,

I have few commented code inside the scheduler properties,

```
<div data-bind="kendoScheduler: { .... //sample }"></div>
```

that's what it throwing this issue to me, but i don't know this is accepted by previous versions of Kendo.

now i just removed the commented lines it is worked for me.

Thanks
Sivan